# What is an equivalent work around to $setOnInsert in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have below collection structure in `mongodb`. Say

**Collection - student -** *_id,firstname,lastname,class*

Now I want to insert 2 extra columns say `marks` as `array`{mark1:m1,mark2:m2}`when inserting a new`row`.

I did it as below but it inserted record excluding `marks` values.

```
var student=new Student({
        _id:id,
        firstname:result.fname,
        lastname:result.lname,
        class:result.class,
        marks:{
            mark1:result.mark.m1,
            mark2:result.mark.m2
        }
})
```

Is this possible in Mongoose?

I came across **[`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert)**, but not sure whether this fits here?

So if it fits, is there any equivalent workaround to use `MongoDb`'s **[`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert)**? if not what approach I could use?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but I think the problem might be that you don't have `marks` in your mongoose model.

Comment: @JorgeAranda.. Yes I do not have it, can extra columns be added runtime which aren't there in model
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but that depends on the options set when defining your schema. You don't necessarily need to use the **[`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert)** operator when inserting a new record, the **[`save()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)** method on the model suffices.

The **[`strict`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)** option ensures that values added to your model instance that were not specified in the schema gets saved or not to the db.

For example, if you had defined your schema like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var studentSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    class: String
})

var Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);
var student= new Student({
    _id: id,
    firstname: result.fname,
    lastname: result.lname,
    class: result.class,
    marks: {
        mark1: result.mark.m1,
        mark2: result.mark.m2
    }
});
student.save(); // marks is not saved to the db
```

But if you set the **[`strict`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)** option to false:

```
var studentSchema = new Schema({..}, { strict: false });
var student= new Student({
    _id: id,
    firstname: result.fname,
    lastname: result.lname,
    class: result.class,
    marks: {
        mark1: result.mark.m1,
        mark2: result.mark.m2
    }
});
student.save(); // marks is now saved to the db!!
```

---

**NOTE**: The strict option is set to false in mongoose v2 by default for backward compatibility. Set it to true and sleep peacefully. Do not set to false unless you have good reason.